# Webpack dev middleware for all routes

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, koa

I configured webpack dev middleware, when I go to index page `/` all works fine, otherwise page `Not Found`, how to make work dev server for all paths ?

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const devMiddleware = require('koa-webpack-dev-middleware')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 3000;

const app = new Koa();
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(devMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  stats: { colors: true },
}));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Dev Server port: "${3000}"`);
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },{
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```